# How to use quality control as an adjective?

Tags: adjectives, compound-adjectives

I'm looking for some synonym expression to convey the fact that a method, or a tool, provides quality controlled output. Or, in other words, that the output produced with such tool is quality controlled via certain reviewing methods.

Somehow, saying *quality controlled* production sounds unnatural to me.

Comment: Stylistically, it could be *quality-controlled production* (with a hyphen). But, that minor point aside, I see nothing wrong with the phrase.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with 'quality-controlled production'. Things often sound unnatural because they're novel. Sounding unnatural is often a fair indication of unacceptability, but this depends on how well attuned to correct practice one's (sometimes metaphorical) ears are.